# Why doesn't this jQuery change my text to red before turning it blue?

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery that is triggered when a part of my page is clicked.

```
$('#my_link').css("color", "red").delay(500).fadeOut(500).css("color", "blue").fadeIn(500)
```

I can see most of the animations happening like the fadeOut and fadeIn but I never see the text turn red. I only see it turn blue. Any idea why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Should be like this:

```
$('#my_link').css("color", "red").delay(500).fadeOut(500, function(){
   $(this).css("color", "blue").fadeIn(500);
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: may be worth marking him as the answer Fendo.  He's used callbacks (see the function() call as the second argument of fadeOut) to ensure that the change of colour to blue only happens *after* the fadeout.  Chaining in jquery is very powerful, but can have some unwanted side effects as the functions run in sequence without necessarily waiting for completion before moving onto the next.  The callback function is your friend in this instance, and you will find it used in a lot of places.

Answer (score 1):

The order in which the function will be executed will be

```
css red --> css blue --> fadeOut --> delay --> fadeIn
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dXSga/

> the `.delay()` method allows us to delay the execution of functions that follow it in the queue.
>   This will not delay the no-arguments forms of `.show()` or `.hide()` which do not use the effects queue.

In short the `.delay()` wont delay `css()` which doesnt use a jQuery [effect](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will work.  As far as I understand the chaining with jQuery does not link attributes with animation effects.  I could be wrong.  By using the callback on the fade out though you can create the effect you want.

```
$('#my_link').css({ color : 'red' }).delay(500).fadeOut(500, function()
{
    $('#my_link').css({ color : 'blue' }).fadeIn(500);
});
```